# PHP class properties NULL even after initialization

Tags: php

I have a problem here,
when I have this class,
class properties NULL even after initialization

```
class User
{
    public $name;
    public $id;
    public $email;
    private $password;

    private $dbconn;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbconn= new Config\Database();
    }
    public function login( $email, $password){
        $matches=$this->dbconn->query("SELECT pwhash from users WHERE email = '$email'");
        if($matches->num_rows==0){
            return "no such user";
        }else{
            while($row =$matches->fetch_assoc()){
                if($row['pwhash']==hash("sha256",$password)){
                $this->name=$row['name'];
                $this->id=$row['id'];

                return "login successful";
            }else{
                return "login fail";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to access class outside the php file,

```
$user = new User\User();
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) ){
    $loginmessage=$user->login($_POST['email'],$_POST['password']);
}
if($loginmessage=="login successful"){
        $userarray= get_object_vars($user);
        var_dump($userarray);

}
```

Then I var_dump `$userarray` which shows

```
["name"]=>
  NULL
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
```

Any reason behind it?

Comment: Remember to properly escape your variables in SQL statements, otherwise you're vulnerable to injection.  The safest (only safe) way to avoid sql injection is to use prepared statements, but otherwise use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or the equivalent for your engine

Comment: A single, unsalted SHA256 is not sufficient for secure password storage. Use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not selecting 'name' or 'id' in your SQL so you are getting NULL when using:

```
$this->name=$row['name'];
$this->id=$row['id'];
```

Change your SQL to be:

```
$matches=$this->dbconn->query("SELECT pwhash,name,id from users WHERE email = '$email'");
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake!